# Why does this code trying all permutations of a list element with all other members, exit with exit status 137?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, corpus

I have a large corpus of text (~170kB) which I want to train for a NLP application.

However, trying to make a list of all the elements of a list, paired with all the other elements of the same list one at a time, causes the program to exit with an exit code 137.

```
def wordsToBigrams(words):
    totalSentenceBigrams = [(a,b) for b in words for a in words]
```

Comment: And how many words are there?

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably running out of memory when building that list. To avoid that, use [the `itertools` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and process each pair as it is generated. Or save the generated pairs to file for later.

Specifically, use the `product` function:

> Equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example, `product(A, B)` returns the same as `((x,y) for x in A for y in B)`.

EDIT: Yes, your script requires large amounts of memory - this is the memory consumption on my machine:

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, I don't have any output yet but the program has not exited. Why does using itertools make a difference and let the program run its course?

Comment: @Ketcomp itertools uses something called generators. I will point you towards [the Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to understand how they work and how to use them. Basically, generators produce the result part by part, so the entire result doesn’t have to be stored in memory at one time.

Comment: @Ketcomp err, I am not sure, I believe I am wrong and itertools uses something called iterators which I am not too sure about :/

Comment: Thanks! Is there a better alternative to using product(a,b)? Is this a language specific delay? Comparable Java code completes execution in ~30 secs.

Comment: @Ketcomp by “comparable”, do you mean that your Java code stores each generated pair in one gigantic array?

Comment: I should probably find out more about the Java code before replying to that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102760/discussion-between-ketcomp-and-rishav).